# Invert progress gauge direction (echarts)

Tags: javascript, echarts

I tried reversing the direction of the gauge's progress bar (Echarts) to achieve this result:

[image]

That is, I need it to start from 0 and go up to 100, but maintaining the position of the angles that is in this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ECharts Gauge Example</title>
    <!-- Inclua a biblioteca ECharts -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.2.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Crie um contêiner para o gráfico -->
    <div id="gaugeChart" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>

    <script>
      // Seu código ECharts aqui
      const gaugeData = [{
          value: 20
        },
        {
          value: 40
        }
      ];

      let myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('gaugeChart'));

      const option = {
        series: [{
          type: 'gauge',
          startAngle: 120,
          endAngle: -90,
          min: 100,
          max: 0,
          pointer: {
            show: false
          },
          axisLabel :{
          color: 'red',
          inverse: true
          },
          progress: {
            show: true,
            overlap: false,
            roundCap: true,
            clip: false
          },
          data: gaugeData
        }]
      };

      myChart.setOption(option);

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

How can I make this adjustment? I tried using `reverse: true` but it didn't work.

He always has the same direction, no matter what I do. I need to keep this format that I've shown in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to this

```js
series: [{
            type: 'gauge',
            clockwise: false,
            ...
            }]
```